# How to Search and modify data of columns on database?

Tags: c#, database, datatable, sql-update

I have two databases.
One have only one column which will store fizic locations, and i have connected it to a dropdown menu.
The second one have all the products with multiple columns, one of them is the location.

I want to add a update location name for my first table, and when this is updated, all the products in the second table which are located on that location, have the location name changed as well.

Unfortunately what i have tried, only create a new location leaving the old one right in place.
On the second table, nothing happens.

NameLabel have the name of the curent location name, received from the previous form.
The textbox have the new name i want to update.

```cs
private void Update_location_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string name = NameLabel.Text;

    SqlCommand dataAdapter = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbLocation SET loc_name = @loc_name WHERE loc_name = '" + name + "'", con);

    dataAdapter.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc_name", textbox_location.Text);
    dataAdapter.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand dataAdapter2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE DB_Main SET Location = @location WHERE Location = '" + name + "'", con);
    dataAdapter2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", textbox_location.Text);
    dataAdapter2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Location updated!");
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Consider using a more modern approach to data access such as Dapper.  Depending on the form technology you're using, there should be a data binding mechanism; you should learn it.

Comment: Also use parameters, you rcurrent code has **dangerous** SQL injection. And the connection, command and adapter need `using` to dispose them, do *not* cache them in fields.

Comment: I second the recommendation to use a "object relational mapper" (ORM). like dapper or [Entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli)

Comment: You have two **tables** in ONE database. You do NOT have two databases. I know it seems pedantic, but when working with computers getting these things right is _important_... computers are the ultimate pedants.

Comment: I will go counter to some other responses, though: there's nothing wrong with doing raw sql and ado.net, and it can be an extremely valuable (and lucrative) skill to develop.

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

1. The update condition should be based on ID.

   ```
   UPDATE dbLocation 
   SET loc_name = @loc_name 
   WHERE loc_id = loc_id
   ```
2. The second table should only contain the `Id` and not the location name that way if the location name changes, it will automatically reflect in the second table (if you have used join)

Comment: I hoped there was a way to make it without an id column, and only use one column in the table. Thank you!

Comment: `WHERE loc_id = loc_id`? Aside from `NULL`, you might just as well remove the WHERE clause completely.